FortiGate and WireGuard UDP hole punching
I am working on a project that uses WireGuard and UDP Hole Punching to create a mesh network between peers. The peers are mostly behind residential home gateways where the hole-punched tunnels work fine. However, my customer is behind a Fortigate firewall and it is not allowing the response traffic from any non-initiated peers. I do not want to put a relay server on their boundary. I want the FortiGate to pass the peer-to-peer traffic. The FortiGate is using a single public IP.
We had a call with a Fortinet Level-3 tech, and he concluded that there is nothing that can be done. The Fortigate is protecting the network. I do agree that UDP hole punching is "a bit of a hack". But it's a popular hack, and I would have thought they would have some kind of "helper" feature to accommodate it.
In the short term, we put the internal devices behind a consumer firewall, and it works. But this is not a good long-term solution.
In this scenario, there are devices:

T1 is a technician's laptop in the office behind a FortiGate
T2 is a technician's laptop in the field (e.g. a cellular hotspot)
C1 is a customer device in their house behind a residential cable modem
H is a cloud rendevous server running wireguard on a static port
All devices are running WireGuard with a program that manages dynamic configuration

What works or not:

All connections to H work correctly
Connections from T2 (in the field) to C1 work correctly
Connections from T1 (in the office) to C1 fail to connect

The connection flow:

T1 connects to H over wg, H makes note of the public ip:port endpoint
C1 connects to H over wg, H makes note of the public ip:port endpoint
T1 and C1 ask H for connection details
H shares the list of known public endpoints for T1's network
T1 and C1 reconfigure their peers to use the known endpoints

The net effect of the connection flow is that C1 tries to connect back to T1 via the port left open for H. And, in the case of the FortiGate, the packets are dropped because they did not originate from H. Most other firewalls seem to allow this.
What I see from "wg" on T1 is that bytes were sent, but no nothing was received. And I see the same from C1.
I find it odd that there is no configuration in the firewall to accommodate this.
I am looking for any and all suggestions as to how I might be able to figure this out. Ideally, in the firewall config. And if I'm just missing something, that's even better...
Thanks

You have to setup a SNAT (VIP) on the side that doesn't initiate. Since wireguard usually initiates out from the client-side (C1 or T1) that means you need a SNAT on the fortigate for the external service (sounds like you've flipped it around to where H is a type of concentrator that initiates?).
Boils down to, setup a SNAT\VIP for the UDP ports for intercept for the non-initiating (answering) side. It should work just fine. Yes, Fortigates tend to be more secure than most of the "firewalls" out there because it is stateful first. If you want this to work without any setup, you can turn on async-routing, but that basically turns the box into a Palo Alto which is just swiss cheese with guillotines (not a real firewall, more of a packet\session broker unless you use "app-default").
